# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, python-2.7, kerberos

I am working with python 2.7.3 and I am trying to install Python Kerberos. But it is giving me the following error:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

The entire traceback is as follows:

```
setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'kerberos' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I want to know if there is any way of resolving the error without installing Visual Studio. It would be great if someone will be able to help resolve these errors.

Comment: I want to know if there is any alternate way to resolve the error.

Comment: You can try MinGW, as also mentionend in the answers to the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Visual Studio (2008), Python is looking for a compiler you don't have.

See this question: [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

---

Note: If you were curious, `vcvarsall.bat` is a shell script that updates your environment to let you compile with Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass the entire process and install python MYSQL without installing Visual Studio?

Comment: @NelsonMenezes Find a precompiled version.